# Why won't checkmarks appear in an TreeListView checkbox when CheckedAspectName name is set (and how do I programmatically set checkboxes)?

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox, objectlistview

My question is based on the `ObjectListView` [gettingstarted code (GettingStartedTree project )](http://sourceforge.net/projects/objectlistview/files/objectlistview/examples/getting-started.zip/download) referred to in the `Getting Started` section of the `ObjectListView` sourceforge online docs.

My goal is to add `checkboxes` to the Title column of the TreeListView in the GettingStartedTree project.

I was able to add checkboxes simply by setting `treeListView1.CheckBoxes` to `true` and setting `treeListView1.CheckedAspectName` to `Title` (see `After making changes` below) as described in the instructions. **Problem:** However, when I run the program and click on a checkbox, a checkmark **does not** appear in the checkbox. I expect that a user should be able to "check" a checkbox on the UI.

Note: If I leave `treeListView1.CheckBoxes` set to `true` and set `treeListView1.CheckedAspectName` to `null`, then a checkmark **does** appear in the checkbox.

Am I configuring the `TreeListView` correctly?

**Before making any changes**

*treeListView1:*

```
CheckBoxes = false
CheckedAspectName = null
```

*OLVColumn Collection, olvColumn1(Title):*

```
Name = olvColumn1
AspectName = Title
CheckBoxes = false (Title column)
```

[image]

**After making changes**

*treeListView1:*

```
CheckBoxes = true
CheckedAspectName = Title
```

*OLVColumn Collection, olvColumn1(Title):*

```
Name = olvColumn1
AspectName = Title
CheckBoxes = false (Title column)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**

> After posting this answer, I came across a `TreeViewList` property
>   named `HierarchicalCheckboxes` that I hadn't noticed before and that I
>   don't see discussed/described anywhere in the `ObjectListView`
>   sourceforge docs. I now believe this is what Grammarian was referring
>   to in his comment under Patricks answer. In my code (in this answer),
>   this property is set false, so I assume I'm **NOT** using
>   `HierarchicalCheckboxes`. I thought hierarchical checkboxes were checkboxes in a model that has a hierarchical structure like the model in my code in this answer.
>
> I guess/assume `HierarchicalCheckboxes` is
>   associated with the write-up on [Hierarchy-aware checkboxes](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/blog7.html) ,
>   although I'm not sure. `ObjectListView` is a great control. I just wish the `ObjectListView` sourceforge docs did a better job differentiating the explaining the collection of lists required to draw the `treeview` portion of a `TreeListView` along with adding and managing checkboxes to such a model both with with and without the use of the `hierarchical checkboxes` feature (enabled by the property `HierarchicalCheckboxes`). I guess all the pieces are in the docs, but its spread out and a bit disjointed.

**End of Update**

For the sake of clarity I was kind of forced to answer this myself.....

Reminder: all this is based on the `gettingstartedcode` described in the original question.

First, the answer to my initial problem was to clear `treeview1.CheckedAspectName` as in the original example code. Doing so resulted in a checkmark appearing in the checkbox (as expected) when the checkbox is clicked.

Grammarian kindly described how to programmatically check/uncheck a checkbox for (I assume) a `non-hierarchical checkbox` scenario, i.e., add a `bool?` or `bool` property to the model and add the property's name to the TreeListView's CheckedAspectName property.

I came to the conclusion that this won't work for `hierarchical checkboxes` because Grammarian said the following and loading the `bool?` or `bool` property's name into CheckedAspectName is required based on his explanation.

> If you are using hierarchical checkboxes, you can't use
>   CheckedAspectName or anything else that eventually installs a
>   CheckStateGetter

So, ignoring the advice that setting the CheckedAspectName property for `hierarchical checkboxes` won't work, I implemented a `bool?` isChecked property at all levels in my hierarchical model. It works fine, i.e., I can now programmatically check a checkbox at any level in the hierarchy via the model.

Code for a simple example follows (I need to write the code to set the tri-state checkbox for parent rows based on the checkedness or uncheckedness of child rows.). The column "# To Keep" is designed to be relevant only for the level-2 items in the hierarchy

The form has only a `FooTreeListView : BrightIdeasSoftware.TreeListView` control on it

[image]

**FooTreeListView.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ObjectListView_TreeListView
{
    class FooTreeListView : BrightIdeasSoftware.TreeListView
    {
        private List<Categories> categoriesList;

        private readonly string[] categoryDescriptors = { "Cat A", "Cat B", "Cat C", "Cat D" };

        internal List<Categories> CategoriesList { get => categoriesList; set => categoriesList = value; }

        public enum CategoryEnum
        {
            CategoryA = 0,
            CategoryB = 1,
            CategoryC = 2,
            CategoryD = 3
        }

        public FooTreeListView() : base()
        {
            CategoriesList = new List<Categories>();
            CategoriesList.Clear();

            CanExpandGetter = delegate (Object x)
            {
                if (x is Categories && ((Categories)x).ItemList.Count > 0)
                {
                    return true;
                }

                if (x is Categories.Item && ((Categories.Item)x).ActionList.Count > 0)
                {return true;
                }

                return false;

            };

            ChildrenGetter = delegate (Object x)
            {
                if (x is Categories)
                    return ((Categories)x).ItemList;

                if (x is Categories.Item)
                    return ((Categories.Item)x).ActionList;

                throw new ArgumentException("Should be Categories or Categories.Item");
            };

            //Load the 4 top-level categories into the tree
            CategoriesList.Add(new Categories(categoryDescriptors[(int)CategoryEnum.CategoryA],false));
            CategoriesList.Add(new Categories(categoryDescriptors[(int)CategoryEnum.CategoryB], false));
            CategoriesList.Add(new Categories(categoryDescriptors[(int)CategoryEnum.CategoryC], false));
            CategoriesList.Add(new Categories(categoryDescriptors[(int)CategoryEnum.CategoryD], false));
        }

        internal class Categories
        {
            private string action;
            private bool? isChecked;
            public string Action { get { return action; } set { action = value; } }
            public bool? IsChecked { get => isChecked; set => isChecked = value; }

            private List<Item> itemList;
            internal List<Item> ItemList { get => itemList; set => itemList = value; }

            public Categories(string action, bool? isChecked)
            {
                this.action = action;
                this.isChecked = isChecked;
                ItemList = new List<Item>();
            }

            internal class Item
            {
                private string action;
                private bool? isChecked;
                private int numberToKeep = 0;
                private List<ItemAction> actionList;

                public string Action { get { return action; } set { action = value; } }
                public int NumberToKeep { get => numberToKeep; set => numberToKeep = value; }
                public bool? IsChecked { get => isChecked; set => isChecked = value; }

                internal List<ItemAction> ActionList { get => actionList; set => actionList = value; }

                internal Item(string action, bool? isChecked, int numberToKeep)
                {
                    this.action = action;
                    this.isChecked = isChecked;
                    this.NumberToKeep = numberToKeep;
                    ActionList = new List<ItemAction>();
                }

                internal class ItemAction
                {
                    private string action;
                    private bool? isChecked;
                    public string Action { get { return action; } set { action = value; } }
                    public bool? IsChecked { get { return isChecked; } set { isChecked = value; } }

                    internal ItemAction(string action, bool? isChecked)
                    {
                        this.action = action;
                        this.isChecked = isChecked;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public void AddCategoryItemName(CategoryEnum category, string itemName, bool? isChecked, int numberToKeep)
        {
            CategoriesList[(int)category].ItemList.Add(new Categories.Item(itemName, isChecked, numberToKeep));
        }

        public void AddItemAction(CategoryEnum category, string itemName, string action, Boolean isChecked)
        {
            Categories.Item itemMatch = CategoriesList[(int)category].ItemList.Find(x => x.Action.Equals(itemName));

            if (itemMatch != null)
            {
                itemMatch.ActionList.Add(new Categories.Item.ItemAction(action, isChecked));
            }
            else
            {
                throw new ArgumentException(String.Format("Can't find treeviewlist item '{0}'->'{1}'", categoryDescriptors[(int)category], itemName));
            }
        }

        public void AddItemAction(CategoryEnum category, string itemName, string action)
        {
            Categories.Item itemMatch = CategoriesList[(int)category].ItemList.Find(x => x.Action.Equals(itemName));

            if (itemMatch != null)
            {
                itemMatch.ActionList.Add(new Categories.Item.ItemAction(action, false));
            }
            else
            {
                throw new ArgumentException(String.Format("Can't find treeviewlist item '{0}'->'{1}'", categoryDescriptors[(int)category], itemName));
            }
        }

        public void LoadTree()
        {
            Roots = CategoriesList;
            ExpandAll();
        }
    }
}
```

**Form1.cs**

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
using static ObjectListView_TreeListView.FooTreeListView;

namespace ObjectListView_TreeListView
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            SuspendLayout();

            xenSnapshotsTreeListView1.AddCategoryItemName(CategoryEnum.CategoryA, "Item A", true, 0);
            xenSnapshotsTreeListView1.AddCategoryItemName(CategoryEnum.CategoryA, "Item B", false, 1);

            xenSnapshotsTreeListView1.AddItemAction(CategoryEnum.CategoryA, "Item A", "Item A foo", true);
            xenSnapshotsTreeListView1.AddItemAction(CategoryEnum.CategoryA, "Item A", "Item A bar", false);

            xenSnapshotsTreeListView1.AddItemAction(CategoryEnum.CategoryA, "Item B", "Item B foo");
            xenSnapshotsTreeListView1.AddItemAction(CategoryEnum.CategoryA, "Item B", "Item B bar", true);

            xenSnapshotsTreeListView1.LoadTree();

            ResumeLayout();
        }
    }
}
```

**Form1.Designer.cs**

```
namespace ObjectListView_TreeListView
{
    partial class Form1
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
            this.xenSnapshotsTreeListView1 = new ObjectListView_TreeListView.FooTreeListView();
            this.olvColumnAction = ((BrightIdeasSoftware.OLVColumn)(new BrightIdeasSoftware.OLVColumn()));
            this.olvColumnNumbSsToKeep = ((BrightIdeasSoftware.OLVColumn)(new BrightIdeasSoftware.OLVColumn()));
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.xenSnapshotsTreeListView1)).BeginInit();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // xenSnapshotsTreeListView1
            // 
            this.xenSnapshotsTreeListView1.AllColumns.Add(this.olvColumnAction);
            this.xenSnapshotsTreeListView1.AllColumns.Add(this.olvColumnNumbSsToKeep);
            this.xenSnapshotsTreeListView1.CellEditUseWholeCell = false;
            this.xenSnapshotsTreeListView1.CheckBoxes = true;
            this.xenSnapshotsTreeListView1.CheckedAspectName = "IsChecked";
            this.xenSnapshotsTreeListView1.Columns.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeader[] {
            this.olvColumnAction,
            this.olvColumnNumbSsToKeep});
            this.xenSnapshotsTreeListView1.Cursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.Default;
            this.xenSnapshotsTreeListView1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
            this.xenSnapshotsTreeListView1.GridLines = true;
            this.xenSnapshotsTreeListView1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
            this.xenSnapshotsTreeListView1.MultiSelect = false;
            this.xenSnapshotsTreeListView1.Name = "xenSnapshotsTreeListView1";
            this.xenSnapshotsTreeListView1.ShowGroups = false;
            this.xenSnapshotsTreeListView1.ShowImagesOnSubItems = true;
            this.xenSnapshotsTreeListView1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(800, 450);
            this.xenSnapshotsTreeListView1.TabIndex = 0;
            this.xenSnapshotsTreeListView1.UseAlternatingBackColors = true;
            this.xenSnapshotsTreeListView1.UseCompatibleStateImageBehavior = false;
            this.xenSnapshotsTreeListView1.View = System.Windows.Forms.View.Details;
            this.xenSnapshotsTreeListView1.VirtualMode = true;
            // 
            // olvColumnAction
            // 
            this.olvColumnAction.AspectName = "Action";
            this.olvColumnAction.Text = "Action";
            this.olvColumnAction.TextAlign = System.Windows.Forms.HorizontalAlignment.Center;
            this.olvColumnAction.Width = 200;
            // 
            // olvColumnNumbSsToKeep
            // 
            this.olvColumnNumbSsToKeep.AspectName = "NumberToKeep";
            this.olvColumnNumbSsToKeep.Text = "# To Keep";
            this.olvColumnNumbSsToKeep.TextAlign = System.Windows.Forms.HorizontalAlignment.Right;
            this.olvColumnNumbSsToKeep.Width = 65;
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(800, 450);
            this.Controls.Add(this.xenSnapshotsTreeListView1);
            this.Name = "Form1";
            this.Text = "Form1";
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.xenSnapshotsTreeListView1)).EndInit();
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }

        #endregion

        private FooTreeListView xenSnapshotsTreeListView1;
        private BrightIdeasSoftware.OLVColumn olvColumnAction;
        private BrightIdeasSoftware.OLVColumn olvColumnNumbSsToKeep;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`HierarchicalCheckboxes` doesn't work with `CheckedAspectName` (or `CheckedAspectGetter`), although finding the documentation on this isn't easy.

Some additional information here:

[Hierarchy-aware checkboxes](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/blog7.html)

Comment: Just to nail it down: You're saying that for `HierarchicalCheckboxes`, the behavior I'm seeing is by design? In other words, for `HierarchicalCheckboxes`, `CheckedAspectName` **MUST** be null? If so, you're right - the docs are sorely lacking :-) `CheckedAspectName` is not mentioned in the `Hierarchy-aware checkboxes` doc.

Comment: It does -- sort of :) The docs do say: " so with hierarchical checkboxes, we don’t allow CheckStateGetters to be installed." CheckedAspectName is a simple wrapper for the CheckStateGetter functionality.

Comment: Actually, are you using the heirarchical version of checkboxes? You didn't say you were.

Comment: I guess I wasn't aware I WAS using heirarchical checkboxes :-). My project requirements demand a treeview control with columns. That's what led me to the ObjectListView control (Excellent work, BTW). A treeview is hierarchical by nature so it didn't occur to me that a `TreeListView` control was special in this way. I'm implementing your answer now. My only wish is that you update your sourceforge docs with your answer. I've been trying to figure out hierarchical checkboxes and how to programmatically check a checkbox for days. I just wasn't finding it clearly stated in the sourceforge docs :-(

Answer (score 1):

Just to make this clear...

To enable checkboxes for the `TreeListView` (or any other version of `ObjectListView`), just set `CheckBoxes` to `true` on the control itself.

That's all you need to do.

If you have a property on your model that indicates whether a row should be checked or not, you can automatically hook that value onto the checkboxes by setting `CheckedAspectName` to the name of that property. For example, if your model has an `IsSelected` property, then this will hook the checkbox to that property:

```
treeListView1.CheckedAspectName = "IsSelected";
```

The type of that property must be `bool` (or `bool?` if you have a tri-state check box). So, in the question, setting the `CheckedAspectName` to "Title" cannot work because `Title` is not a boolean.

Don't change any value in any **column** to get checkboxes to work.

If you are using hierarchical checkboxes, you can't use `CheckedAspectName` or anything else that eventually installs a `CheckStateGetter`. The docs on the [Hierarchy-aware checkboxes](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/blog7.html) page that Patrick mentioned explain why.

Comment: As my comment on Patrick's answer said, I went to implement your answer but these two statements of yours seem mutually exclusive: _"If you have a property on your model that indicates whether a row should be checked or not, you can automatically hook that value onto the checkboxes by setting CheckedAspectName to the name of that property."_ and _"If you are using hierarchical checkboxes, you can't use CheckedAspectName or anything else that eventually installs a CheckStateGetter."_. Are you saying that checkboxes for a `TreeListView` with hierarchical checkboxes can't be programmatically set?